Значення суфіксів -ість, -ність
Думав про те, що правильніше вживати в значенні відстані - дальність чи далекість, наприклад дал..ість польоту. І замислився на значенням суфікса -ність чи -ість.
Знайшов таке:

За допомогою словотвірних моделей типу: прикметник + суфікси -ість, -от(а), -ин(а), -изн(а), -н- утворюються терміни на позначення поняття «абстрактна ознака», що вказує на певні властивості реальних об’єктів.
У творенні таких термінів позицію домінанти займає суфікс -ість. Ці терміни називають абстрактні властивості (динамічність, компактність, еквівалентність); властивості, що визначаються кількісними ознаками (дублетність, примірниковість, періодичність, повторюваність); фізико-хімічні властивості (вогкість, еластичність, рухомість); властивості на позначення «психологічних особливостей осіб» (зацікавленість, очитаність, поінформованість, читальність); статистичні показники (коефіцієнти) (відвідуваність, обертаність, читаність, місткість).
Терміни, що виражають абстрактну ознаку, становлять сполучення твірних основ якісних і відносних прикметників із суфіксом -ість (-ність): дискретність, комплектність, раритетність. Формант -ість приєднується як до власномовної, так і до іншомовної твірної основи: інформативність, доступність.
Лексеми із загальним словотвірним значенням «абстрактна ознака» мотивуються прикметниками із суфіксами: -н- (дискретний — дискретність, еквівалентний — еквівалентність, комплектний — комплектність); -ов- (примірниковий — примірниковість, вибірковий — вибірковість); -л- (стислий — стислість); -альн- (читальний — читальність); -к- (місткий — місткість); -ичн- (-ічн-) (періодичний — періодичність, публічний — публічність, стохастичний — стохастичність).
Лексеми, утворені шляхом приєднання суфіксів -от(а), -ин(а), -изн(а) до основ якісних прикметників, самостійно в УДТ не вживаються, а функціюють винятково у складі термінів-словосполук: глибина індексування, глибина комплектування, хронологічна глибина фонду (бібліографічного пошуку); повнота фонду (бібліографічних відомостей, бібліографічного опису, бібліографічного пошуку, каталогу, комплектування фонду, виконання бібліографічного запиту); частота поновлення інформації; новизна інформації.
Використання однотипних словотвірних моделей для номінації властивостей як родових понять можна проілюструвати на таких прикладах: а) властивості інформації: єдність із фізичним носієм, дискретність, неперервність, наявність смислу і новизни, цінність, кумулятивність, зростання, повторюваність, багаторазова використовуванність, старіння, розпорошення у джерелах; б)властивості фонду: цілісність, відкритість, множинність, динамічність, інформативність, керованість, кумулятивність, стохастичність, гетерогенність, надійність; в) властивості каталогів: інформаційність, науковість, доступність, відповідність змісту і побудови каталогів потребам читачів,повнота, багатоаспектність, відтворення фонду, оперативність.
Можна стверджувати, що в термінології спостерігаємо високий ступінь спеціалізації форманта -ість для позначення властивостей, показників. Водночас певні властивості можуть бути номіновані за допомогою формантів -от(а), -нн(я) та описової конструкції. Використання описових конструкцій, які здебільшого є дефініцією поняття, свідчать про відсутність точного, однозначного, лаконічного україномовного терміна. Шляхом усунення описових конструкцій термінів на позначення властивостей може бути використання словотвірної моделі із суфіксом -ість: від основи англійського терміна relevance за допомогою суфікса -ість утворено термін релевантність фонду (відповідність змісту документів читацькому попиту).
Творення термінів соціальної комунікації, Марія Комова

Якщо абстрактна ознака це єдине значення цих суфіксів, то ані далекість, ані дальність не пасують значенню відстані в кілометрах. Чи я помиляюсь?
